# HTTP 500 Error - When trying to update a field in a Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, error, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Designer 2013 (2013 workflow on a Document Library)

After much research I have found potential solutions were to:

1. Set `Required documents to be checked out before they can be edited?` to `NO`

**or**

2. Un-Check `Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name`

In my case both of these ideas have been tried with no success. I get a

> HTTP 500 Error

when trying to update a field in a Workflow on a Create (upload), only.

Any ideas on causes?

Comment: Can you show us your workflow logic?

Comment: Can you capture failed request in Fiddler?

Comment: Workflow Logic is this:
Stage: Stage 1
If Current Item:Document Title not equal 1
Set Document title to 1

Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow